# Which locator to use? I am using xpath but it is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Which locator to use for my code?

I tried using Xpath but for some reason xpath is not working.
xpath:

```
//*[@id="ext-gen25"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen25']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a")).click();

<a href="repopulateUser.jsp?authAuthSessionId=6956CCD74D7E4BFEA867561228528EF3&amp;r=eyJyb2xlSWQiOiI0OTg3ZjJmNC05Y2E1LTExZTgtOWEzNy0wMDUwNTY4ODE3ZWYiLCJyb2xlTmFtZSI6IkRhdGEgTWFuYWdlciIsInJvbGVDb2RlIjoiREFUQU1BTkFHRVIiLCJyb2xlR3JwSWQiOiJmNGMxMWNhNy05YzFiLTExZTgtOWEzNy0wMDUwNTY4ODE3ZWYiLCJzdHVkeUlkIjoiYjQ0ODg2ZjgtYWM5ZS0xMWU4LWJiNGItMDA1MDU2ODgxN2VmIiwibW9kdWxlcyI6WyJFWENIQU5HRSJdfQ==" class="labels">Data Manager [eXchange]</a>
```

By clicking on that hyperlink the system should navigate to X module.

Comment: <a href="repopulateUser.jsp?authAuthSessionId=6956CCD74D7E4BFEA867561228528EF3&amp;r=eyJyb2xlSWQiOiI0OTg3ZjJmNC05Y2E1LTExZTgtOWEzNy0wMDUwNTY4ODE3ZWYiLCJyb2xlTmFtZSI6IkRhdGEgTWFuYWdlciIsInJvbGVDb2RlIjoiREFUQU1BTkFHRVIiLCJyb2xlR3JwSWQiOiJmNGMxMWNhNy05YzFiLTExZTgtOWEzNy0wMDUwNTY4ODE3ZWYiLCJzdHVkeUlkIjoiYjQ0ODg2ZjgtYWM5ZS0xMWU4LWJiNGItMDA1MDU2ODgxN2VmIiwibW9kdWxlcyI6WyJFWENIQU5HRSJdfQ==" class="labels">Data Manager [eXchange]</a>

Comment: Here you are showing a complex xpath. Could you please try to write a reproducible problem here by adding both the xpath and the target dom? Something else about the context could help us answer.

Comment: Xpath is //*[@id="ext-gen25"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a

Answer (score 0):

If this `Data Manager [eXchange]` text is unique you could stick to it and omit the parent table:

```
//a[text()='Data Manager [eXchange]']
```

Demo:

[image]

If you need to match the link for the specific row it is more tricky but still possible, you will need to share your [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics) code so we could come up with the right expression, an example one would be something like:

```
//table/tr/td[count(//table/tr/th[.='the header you're looking for']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]/a[text()='Data Manager [eXchange]']
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Also be aware of [Table class](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) which is a part of [HtmlElements framework](http://htmlelements.qatools.ru), it makes working with tables much easier